# Transition effects in population pyramid

Tags: d3.js

I am working on a population pyramid that has an updating function.

http://bricbracs.com/hh/

As you can see the bars expand and contract in a horizontal line when you update it with new data. I want to modify the transition effect so that the bars enter and exit vertically like this:

http://vis.stanford.edu/jheer/d3/pyramid/shift.html

I have been following this tutorial and modifying the code but so far no luck.

https://strongriley.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html

Here is the code that first draws the bars on loading. (this is the male bar group, the female bar group is the same)

```
leftBarGroup.selectAll('.bar.left')
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append('rect')
 .attr('class', 'bar left')
 .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.group); })
 .attr("width", 0)
 .attr("opacity", 0)
 .transition()
 .duration(500)
 .attr('width', function(d) { return xScale(d.male); })
 .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())  
 .attr("opacity", 1)
```

And here is the corresponding part of the code in the updating function which changes the bars.

```
var sel = leftBarGroup.selectAll('.bar.left')  
 .attr('class', 'bar left')
 .data(data) 
 .data(data, function(d) { return d.male; })
 .transition()
 .attr('y',0)
 .duration(500)
 .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.group); })
 .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
 .attr('width', function(d) { return xScale(d.male); })
 .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to reproduce the effect in your linked example.  I offset the bars and then slide them back into place.  You then handle the top and bottom bars slightly different.

*Note*, I only did the slide down on the male side of the pyramid, if you need help going the rest of the way just leave me a comment.

```
  var sel = leftBarGroup.selectAll('.bar.left')
    .attr('class', 'bar left')
    .data(data)
    .data(data, function(d) {
      return d.male;
    })
    // offset y to slide down
    .attr('y', function(d){
      var self = d3.select(this);
      return +self.attr('y') - yScale.rangeBand();
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    // slide it back into place
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return yScale(d.group);
    })
    // and set new width
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.male);
    });

  // for the very top bar
  // not only slide it but "fade it in"
  leftBarGroup.select(':last-child')
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .style('opacity', 1)
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return yScale(d.group);
    });

  // append a fake bar on the bottom
  // to slide and fade out
  leftBarGroup.append('rect')
    .attr('y', function(d) {
        return yScale('0-4');
      })
    .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
    .attr('width', function(){
      return leftBarGroup.select(':first-child').attr('width');
    })
    .style('fill', 'steelblue')
    .style('opacity', 0.6)
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr('y', function(d) {
        return yScale('0-4') + yScale.rangeBand();
      })
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .remove();
```

**EDITS**

Going up is just a matter of reversing the logic:

```
var sel = leftBarGroup.selectAll('.bar.left')
    .attr('class', 'bar left')
    .data(data)
    .data(data, function(d) {
      return d.male;
    })
    // offset y to slide up
    .attr('y', function(d){
      var self = d3.select(this);
      return +self.attr('y') + yScale.rangeBand()
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    // slide it back into place
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return yScale(d.group);
    })
    // and set new width
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.male);
    });

  // for the very bottom bar
  // not only slide it but "fade it in"
  leftBarGroup.select(':first-child')
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .style('opacity', 1)
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return yScale(d.group);
    });

  // append a fake bar on the top
  // to slide and fade out
  var w = leftBarGroup.select(':last-child').attr('width');
  leftBarGroup.append('rect')
    .attr('class','fake')
    .attr('y', function(d) {
        return yScale('90+');
      })
    .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
    .attr('width', w)
    .style('fill', 'steelblue')
    .style('opacity', 0.6)
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr('y', function(d) {
        return yScale('90+') - yScale.rangeBand();
      })
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .remove();
```

Updated code sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NRL5lgkPE1C8ANCiRinr?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks great. Is there a way to reverse the animation effect so the motion is sliding up from the bottom and moving upwards instead of top to bottom. I should be able to figure out the female side. Again thanks a lot